# hyperledger real use case (infrastructure management)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm new to hyperledger. I'm reading your docs and tutorial which are great but...
I have a couple of questions.

Since HL network can have several peers none of them owning it at all, who takes cares of the ordering service or the "core" infrastructure (channels,...)? which would be the best approach to install/manage it? Is one peer taking care of it? this gives preferential role for that peer (for instance, if for any reason the one that owns the ordering process or channel is turned it down the entire blockchain would be out of service)

which would be a real scenario where peers are distributed physically? (in terms of running processes/infrastructure management)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In hyperledger fabric, we have peer nodes and ordering nodes. Peer nodes stores all the transaction logs, while the ordering nodes form the block and send it to the peers.

Instead of having one ordering org, you can have multiple ordering orgs joining the channel